# In Google Sheets how to scan entire column(s) for error cells and replace content with content from the cell above?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a sheet that's recording new rows at the bottom with new values every hour or so.
Sometimes the API call gets some error. I changed the error message for `loading…` but I would still like for there to be a way to filter out these errors from the columns and replace this values with the values taken from the cell just above, if this one has no error.

So this is an example of the cells with the errors:
[image]

This is how the array looks like retrieved with the code I used below:
[image]

I started with this:

```
function deleteErrors () {
let sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("CELL_ERRORS");
let checkRange = sheet.getRange(1, 1, sheet.getLastRow(), 2).getDisplayValues();
let rangeReversed = checkRange.reverse();
console.log(rangeReversed);
}
```

How can I remove the `"Loading…"` and replace it with the value of the cell just above IF the cell above has no error, or in the case of the array of arrays with the value below since I used reverse. I used reverse because the idea is to filter from the bottom as the rows are being recorded on the bottom.

So this is how it should look after the correct script is applied:
[image]

And the array of arrays should like like this:
[image]

But this array of arrays is not that important I guess.
Basically I just need for the cells with the `Loading…` error to be overwritten with the value of the cell just above, if that cell above does not have also `Loading…` of course.

Is this possible? Maybe there is some way of using a formula for this but I prefer to use Apps Script.

I tried something like this:

```
function deleteErrors () {

let sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("CELL_ERRORS");
let checkRange = sheet.getRange(1, 1, sheet.getLastRow(), 2).getDisplayValues();
let rangeReversed = checkRange.reverse();
console.log(rangeReversed);

// Get row numbers of cells on col 1 with errors
let cellsCol1 = sheet.getRange(1, 1, sheet.getLastRow(), 1).createTextFinder("Loading…").findAll().map(x => x.getRowIndex());
console.log(cellsCol1);

// Get row numbers of cells on col 1 above the ones with error (hopefully these won't have errors!)
let okCellsCol1 = cellsCol1.map(x => x - 1);
console.log(okCellsCol1);

// Get row numbers of cells on col 2 with errors
let cellsCol2 = sheet.getRange(1, 2, sheet.getLastRow(), 2).createTextFinder("Loading…").findAll().map(x => x.getRowIndex());
console.log(cellsCol2);

// Get row numbers of cells on col 2 above the ones with error (hopefully these won't have errors!)
let okCellsCol2 = cellsCol2.map(x => x - 1);
console.log(okCellsCol2);

}
```

It's not working but how can I go from here?

My file:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ExXtmQ8nyuV1o_UtabVJ-TifIbORItFMWjtN6ZlruWc/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: "So this is an example:" is the sample input situation? If my understanding is correct, can you provide the sample output situation you expect as an image?

Comment: Ok I just edited the question. I hope it's more clear.

Comment: Thank you for replying and providing the sample output situation. From your updated question, I proposed an answer. Could you please confirm it? If that was not useful, I apologize.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- You want to achieve the following situation. (Those images are from OP's question.)

  - From

    [image]
  - To

    [image]

In this case, how about the following modified script?

#### Modified script:

```
let sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("CELL_ERRORS");
let checkRange = sheet.getRange(1, 1, sheet.getLastRow(), 2).getDisplayValues();

// I modified below script.
const values = checkRange.map(([a, b], i, ar) => {
  if (i > 0) {
    return [a == "Loading…" ? ar[i - 1][0] : a, b == "Loading…" ? ar[i - 1][1] : b];
  }
  return [a, b];
});
console.log(values)
```

#### Note:

- In this modified script, when the 1st row includes `Loading…`, `Loading…` is used. If you want to replace this with others, please tell me.

#### Reference:

- [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

### Added:

About `How can we overwrite the values back onto the cells?` and `How can we overwrite the values back onto the cells? Also in my main file I have 21 columns. This will work for 2 columns. If I add the 3rd it won't do the same for the 3rd column in the array. Finally if 2 cells in a row have error (one on top of the other), the Loading… won't disappear.` in the comment, I updated the above script as follows.

#### Modified script:

```js
let sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("CELL_ERRORS");
let checkRange = sheet.getRange(1, 1, sheet.getLastRow(), 3);
const currentValues = checkRange.getDisplayValues();
const transposed = currentValues[0].map((_, c) => currentValues.map(r => r[c]));
const transposedValues = transposed.map(row => {
  let temp = "";
  return row.map((e, i) => {
    if (i > 0) {
      if (e == "Loading…") {
        return temp;
      } else {
        temp = e;
      }
    } else {
      temp = e;
    }
    return e;
  });
});
const values = transposedValues[0].map((_, c) => transposedValues.map(r => r[c]));
console.log(values)
checkRange.setValues(values);
```

- In this modification, I think that your additional situations might be filled.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. It works on the array. How can we overwrite the values back onto the cells? Also in my main file I have 21 columns. This will work for 2 columns. If I add the 3rd it won't do the same for the 3rd column in the array. Finally if 2 cells in a row have error (one on top of the other), the `Loading…` won't disappear. Would you like if I placed another question for this specific request if you feel it's something different from my original question? I'd be happy fo accept your answer for this one and place another one. Or if you like we can continue here. Thank you.

Comment: @Verminous From `About `It works on the array.`, I'm, glad. About your additional situations, I added one more modified script in my answer. Could you please confirm it? If that was not the result you expect, I apologize.

Comment: It works: errors on the cells are replaced by the value on the cells above. It also works with 2 or more cells with errors on top of each other. There's just one thing though: When the range is diferent from `(1,1)` the code will add new empty rows and columns. If it starts at for ex: `(100, 2)` it will add 100 new empty rows at the bottom and 1 new empty column on the right. How to prevent this? The line of code of which I speak is this: let `checkRange = sheet.getRange(100, 2, sheet.getLastRow(), sheet.getLastColumn());`. The `setValue()` line at the end adds the new rows and columns.

Comment: @Verminous Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand about your current issue of your additional question from `(1,1)`, `(100, 2)` and `checkRange = sheet.getRange(100, 2, sheet.getLastRow(), sheet.getLastColumn());` which is not used in my modified script and your script. So can you provide the detail information of it? By this, I would like to try to understand it.

Comment: It's ok. So on your code on the 2nd line we get the range with this: `let checkRange = sheet.getRange(1, 1, sheet.getLastRow(), 3);`. More specifically the first part: `sheet.getRange(1, 1...`. So when the range is set for `(1,1...` it does not create extra empty rows or columns. On my main file I need to change those coordinates for something like: row number `6500` and column number `2`, or `sheet.getRange(6500 2, sheet.getLastRow(), 3);`.  So this for some reason will cause the code to create `6499` extra empty rows at the bottom, and `1` extra empty column at the right. Can this be fixed?

Comment: So for example on my test file I did an experiment and used `let checkRange = sheet.getRange(2, 2, sheet.getLastRow(), 3);`. This will cause the code to create 1 empty rown at the bottom, and 1 empty column on the right.

Comment: @Verminous Thank you for replying. About `sheet.getRange(6500, 2, sheet.getLastRow(), 3);`, in this case, `sheet.getLastRow()` is the all data rows. In this case, the rows are retrieved from 6500 to 6500 + `sheet.getLastRow()`. If you want to retrieve the data rows from 6500 to the last row, how about modifying it to `sheet.getRange(6500, 2, sheet.getLastRow() - 6499, 3);`? But if I misunderstood your additional question, I apologize again.

Comment: @Verminous By the way, in this case, please be careful about the column number. `sheet.getRange(6500, 2, sheet.getLastRow() - 6499, 3);` retrieves the columns B, C and D.

Comment: @Verminous And also, about `let checkRange = sheet.getRange(2, 2, sheet.getLastRow(), 3);`, in this case, how about `let checkRange = sheet.getRange(2, 2, sheet.getLastRow() - 1, 3);`?

Comment: Thank you. I will add some code to the bottom of my question in order to illustrate what I'm doing with an explanation.

Comment: @Verminous Thank you for replying. I deeply apologize for my poor English skill again. In order to correctly understand your current situation and your additional question, can you provide the sample Spreadsheet including the sample values, and also, can you include the sample output you expect? By this, I would like to try to understand it.

Comment: That solution of providing negative coordinate at the end of `getRange` fixed it. Very simple. I had no idea you could fix it that way. Thank you very much! I accepted your answer. Your English is very good. No need to apologize. I am the one to apologize for asking so much.

Comment: @Verminous Thank you for replying. From your replying, I understood your issue was resolved. I'm glad about it. Thank you, too.